# produces the wrong output

Tags: python, debugging

I am trying to create a Python program that generates ten random integers
 this is generating the wrong output

```
def main():

    nums = [5, 3, 7, 9]

    myfile = open('nums_file.txt','w')

    for num in nums:
        myfile.write(str(num) + '/n')

      myfile.close()
      print('File created')
main()



infile = open('nums_file.txt','r')
line = infile.readline()

while line != '':
    num = int(line)
    total += num
    nums.append(num)
    line = infile.readline()

print(nums)
print('Total of list is',total)
```

Comment: How does the file come into it? There's no mention of it in the problem statement.

Comment: what does your input look like?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `random.randint`?

Comment: ">>>" is characteristic of the interactive interpreter, which usually appears when you run `python` from the command line without any arguments. Are you using the command line? If so, how are you executing your script? "myfile.py" or "python myfile.py" will work, but "python" won't.

Comment: allowed to use anything as far as I know. the instructions from the teacher is whats posted at the start. was having trouble with this program so I went to the school and a tutor told me I needed to write the first part of this just like I have it on here. Im pretty sure this cannot be right so im here looking for any help I can get.

Comment: What _is_ the output? What is the expected output?

Comment: the expected out put is for this program to generate ten random integers, all from 1-100, and stores them in a list. Using a loop, I want to process the list to determine the sum of the odd numbers and the sum of the even numbers, then display these sums. I had this written above the code

Comment: Did it ever occur to you to Google for `python random`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be making reading a file a lot more complicated than it need to be. If you want to read all the lines in the file just use `for line in infile`, also in your created file you are adding each `num`  on one line, not on individual lines so your file will actually look like `5/n3/n7/n9/n` which would cause an error trying to cast using `num = int(line)`.

```
import random 

nums = [5, 3, 7, 9]

with  open('nums_file.txt','w') as f:
    for num in nums:
        f.write("{}\n".format(num))



with open('nums_file.txt') as in_file: # use with to automatically close your files
    nums = []
    tot = 0
    for line in in_file:
        num = int(line) 
        tot += num
        nums.append(num)
    print(nums)
    print('Total of list is',tot)
    print ("Total of odd numbers = {}".format(sum(x for x in nums if x % 2)))
    print ("Total of even numbers = {}".format(sum(x for x in nums if not x % 2)))
    rnd_10 = random.sample(nums,10) # get 10 random numbers from the list
```

If you just want ten random numbers from `1 - 100` you can just pass `range` to `random.sample()`

```
 random.sample(range(1,101),10)
```